# Minecraft world transfer

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My friend and I have a Minecraft world on our Xbox that we would like to transfer to my android device is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 4):

No. Xbox stores Minecraft worlds in a different format than Pocket Edition. Maybe if you were a developer, but otherwise no.

If you wanted to *play* in that world on your Android, Minecraft now supports cross-platform multiplayer.

Comment: Does Realms work between Xbox and PE? I didn't think it did.

Comment: It does, and so does LAN multiplayer.

Comment: I don't see any info about Realms for Xbox on the website. Every source I find says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this time the only cross-platform capable versions are Windows 10 and Pocket Edition.